# get row number for table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I use the following query:

```
SELECT ROWNUM SNO,NAME,DEPT FROM TTABLE
```

And the result is:

```
ROWNUM  NAME    DEPT
1       ABC     IT
2       DEF     IT
3       GHI     CSE
```

But what I want is that for each new `dept` the `rownum` starts with 1 again:

```
ROWNUM  NAME    DEPT
1       ABC     IT
2       DEF     IT
1       GHI     CSE
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is your rownum? is it field?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY NAME)`

Comment: Its Working thank u...

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
select count(DEPT) as ROWNUM, NAME, DEPT  from TTABLE group by DEPT;
```

it will give you,

```
ROWNUM  NAME    DEPT
1       ABC     IT
2       DEF     IT
1       GHI     CSE
```

Comment: No, it will fail because NAME is not in GROUP BY. And if it wouldn't fail, it would return a different result.

Comment: @dnoeth name is one of the field in that table. and i tried this query before i post. it works for me. here i am grouping based on dept because we need all dept and its count. might be result will be unique group

Comment: No, you didn't try this query before post. It's tagged `Oracle` and thus it will fail. MySQL will allow the syntax, but return a different result. If it actually works for you can you please set it up as a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com or http://rextester.com?